# How can I store a phone number input into a int array? C

Tags: c, arrays, int, scanf

I am creating a program which stores a name and a number from an input into a data structure. At the moment, I am trying to just make a simple function which gets the input (name and number) and inserts it into to two arrays. My input has to be in the format: name number. e.g

```
John 07745234574
```

which would then store the name in a character array and the number in a int array. The problem is it doesn't print the 0 at the beginning of the number, and adds a load of repeated numbers to then followed by numerous 0's when printed.

my code:

```
int main (void) {
char nme[20];
int nmbr[11];

printf("Enter:");
scanf("%s %d", nme, nmbr);

printf("\n%s ", nme);

int i;
for(i = 0; i<11; i++) {
    printf("%d", nmbr[i]);
    }
return 0;
}
```

I know that using %d wont work but I don't know another way of doing it without perhaps using a loop. Also, how would I store a number if it had a plus sign before it e.g +442962000292

Comment: Where is `nme` pointing?

Comment: Please do not edit your question to make it "solved". It invalidates the entire concept of Stack Overflow. You may want to read the [Introductory Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) some time.

Comment: Why the downvotes, people? The new guy can't be 100% perfect, and he did at least post some code. Yes, he _should_ have read the introductory tour, but he prolly didn't even know it was there until now (thanks, @Jongware, for the link).  Back in the day, we welcomed newbies, now it seems like we drive them away :-(

Comment: @Mawg: when registering a-new you are offered to take the tour. ...perhaps that needs a **bigger font**. Possibly also `<blink>`.

Comment: Why the desire to use `int` for the digits at all? Phone numbers aren't numbers, they are strings; their digits are just characters with no arithmetical meaning.

Comment: I have changed it so both the name and number are stored as strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char *nme;    
int* nmbr;
```

`nme` and `nmbr` are pointers and you should assign some memory before writing something to it.

Read phone number also as a string.

Comment: "Read phone number also as a string" and use atoi() to make sure that it really is a number

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing now is you're storing the phone number into the first element of the int array nmbr. Which means that only nmbr[0] contains a value, and the rest (1 to 11) is just garbage (mostly 0 probably).
The reason for that is that scanf takes an integer pointer (as nmbr is) and stores the value it read from stdin into this integer. It doesn't care that nmbr belongs to a larger array, it just fills the first element. Now since the number you gave is larger than an integer can hold, the value is cut off and not everything of that number is parsed to an int. This is why you receive the strange behaviour.

I would reccomend to store the phone number as a string as well, because you never need to calculate with it, do you? The fact that this string only contains numbers doesn't matter. It's still more a string than it is an integer.

Answer (score 2):

If code still wants to save the phone number as an integer suggest storing the the number's value and length.

For line input, suggest `fgets()`, then `sscanf()`.

```
int main (void) {
  char nme[20];
  unsigned long long nmbr;
  int nmbr_len;

  printf("Enter:");
  char buf[100];
  fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);

  int n[2];
  if (sscanf("%19s %n%llu%n", nme, &n[0], &nmbr, &n[1]) != 2) {
    Handle_BadInput();
  }
  nmbr_len = n[1] - n[0];

  printf("%s %0*llu\n",  nme, nmbr_len, nmbr);
  return 0;
}
```

Input `John 07745234574`
Output `John 07745234574`

---

Some added thoughts: OP's 2 example phone numbers below, if left as a string, need at least `char nmbr[13]`.

```
07745234574
442962000292
```

Even higher upper limits of 15+ digits or 24 digits, separators, prefixes codes, pauses, extensions, etc. imply a robust solution may need to cope with a lengthy string.

Note: many answers here work with the famous phone number [867-5309](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/867-5309/Jenny)

Answer (score 1):

As you can tell from the variety of answer, there are many, many ways to approach this problem. You mentioned you ultimately will store the values in some `data structure`. That brings up a good point to consider. Rather than storing each of the values in separate arrays, you are far better served keeping the values in a collection (such as a `struct`) so that you eliminate needing to keep track of indexing on multiple containers holding `pieces` of your data.

That's not to say using multiple pigeon-holes is wrong, rather if you approach a problem by thinking about an efficient container for your data in the beginning, it can simplify the coding required and make your code more robust.

Since you are reading data from `stdin`, I will second all recommendations that you read an entire `line` of data into a buffer, using **line-oriented input** (`fgets` or `getline`) rather than trying to pigeon-hole it into a `scanf` format string (you can use `scanf` for line-oriented input as well, but the others offer a few advantages).

As you go forward, with your project, managing the memory used by your data will be important. Rather than statically allocating `X` amount of storage, you will probably want to allocate memory as needed. (you still allocate some initial chunk of storage, but you can easily expand as needed as your data grows.

Keeping those considerations in mind, the following is a quick example of how to incorporate them while providing a fairly flexible data input routine that will handle `name number`, `first last number`, `first middle last, suffix number`, etc.... It is commented reasonably. If you have questions, just drop a comment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXL 100

/* typedef to name and number struct */
typedef struct {
    char *name;
    char *num;
} nandn;

int main () {

    char *line = NULL;  /* buffer for getline (NULL forces allocation)  */
    size_t n = 0;       /* maximum no. of char to read (0 - no limit)   */
    ssize_t nchr = 0;   /* number of characters actually read           */
    int idx = 0;        /* counter for array of struct index            */
    char *p = NULL;     /* general char pointer to use for parsing      */

    nandn *nnlist = calloc (MAXL, sizeof (nnlist)); /* allocate MAXL structs    */

    printf ("\nEnter name and number to add to book [ctrl+d] when done.\n\n"); 

    while (printf( " name number: ") && 
            (nchr = getline (&line, &n, stdin)) != -1) {

        if (line[nchr-1] == '\n')               /* strip newline                */
            line[--nchr] = 0;

        p = strrchr (line, ' ');                /* find last space              */
        if (!p) break;                          /* exit read - invalid input    */
        (nnlist + idx)->num = strdup (++p);     /* read number                  */
        *(--p) = 0;                             /* return to space and set null */
        (nnlist + idx)->name = strdup (line);   /* read name (all else in line) */

        idx++;              /* NOTE: if idx = MAXL - 1
                            * reallocate nnlist     */
    }

    if (line) free (line);  /* free memory allocated by getline */
    printf ("\n\nThe information collected was:\n\n");

    int i = 0;              /* print all values in nnlist array */
    while ((nnlist + i)->name) {
        printf ("  nnlist[%d]   %-24s  %s\n", i, (nnlist + i)->name, (nnlist + i)->num);
        i++;
    }
    printf ("\n");

    i = 0;                  /* free all memory for nnlist       */ 
    while ((nnlist + i)->name) {
        free ((nnlist + i)->name);
        free ((nnlist + i)->num);
        i++;
    }
    free (nnlist);

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$./bin/namnum

Enter name and number to add to book [ctrl+d] when done.

 name number: Jane Doe, Md. 8005551212
 name number: Mike M. Mills, Jr. 2145551212
 name number: Alphred Funk, III 2025551212
 name number:

The information collected was:

  nnlist[0]   Jane Doe, Md.             8005551212
  nnlist[1]   Mike M. Mills, Jr.        2145551212
  nnlist[2]   Alphred Funk, III         2025551212
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    unsigned long long num;
    printf("Enter: ");
    scanf("%llu",&num);
    int i=9,n;
    unsigned int array[10];

    while(num>0)
   {
        n=num%10;
        array[i]=n;
        num=num/10; 
        i--;
   }

   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
       printf("%u",array[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: You may need to add some description to explain your code.